# Fetch DATETIME data from database using RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, mariadb, rmysql

I am trying to fetch data from a mariaDB using RMySQL. One of the columns is called `delivery_date` and is of type `DATETIME`.

When writing data to this table, I use character dates in the format "YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS". This format is recognized by the DBMS and it even transforms my dates from CET to UTC timezone. So far so good.

Now when I want to fetch data from this table (or just the column `delivery_date`) I use the following query:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), group = 'group1',               
                 unix.sock='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock')
q <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT delivery_date FROM `id_transactions`")
dbFetch(q)
```

This results in

```
        delivery_date
1 1970-01-01 00:59:59
2 1970-01-01 00:59:59
3 1970-01-01 00:59:59
4 1970-01-01 00:59:59
5 1970-01-01 00:59:59
6 1970-01-01 00:59:59
```

which is not correct. In the DBMS the data looks fine:

[image]

Any idea if this is a bug or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**:

**As it turned out, this error occurs when using the current development version from github. When switching to the latest stable version on CRAN it works fine.**

If it may help you:

I append data to the table using

```
dbWriteTable(con, 'id_transactions', x, append = T, row.names = NA)
```

where the data.table `x` has exactly the form of the SQL table.

The CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `id_transactions` (
 `market` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
 `delivery_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `delivery_hour` tinyint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `delivery_quarter` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `volume` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `marketarea_buy` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
 `marketarea_sell` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
 `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 KEY `idx_delivery_date` (`delivery_date`),
 KEY `idx_delivery_hour` (`delivery_hour`),
 KEY `idx_delivery_quarter` (`delivery_quarter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

Comment: Did you check this already: https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/17

Comment: Please show the entire code you used to generate that output.  My guess is that the problem is with this code, as the insert appears to have been done successfully.

Comment: This is all the code (only thing missing is the line establishing the connection).

Comment: @lloiacono I did (I did the last post). But for me it looked like Hadley closed that issue...

Comment: Something strange going on.  Please provide a sample `INSERT` query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: What is CRAN?  And updating it solved the problem?

Comment: All columns are `NULLable`, hence optional?  (Not a typical situation.)  No `PRIMARY KEY` -- not good.  Think about reasonable-sized `VARCHARs`, not blindly `TEXT`.

Comment: Thank you for your ocmments! I will incorporate them. It is a test DB/table and not yet final. CRAN is "The Comprehensive R Archive Network". The problem I encountered might be related to the driver package RMySQL and to any database system itself.

Comment: *...and NOT to any database system itself.